# Ubuntu randomly reboots on Dell Inspiron 13 7000 2-in-1

Tags: 18.04, dell, hardware, overheating, inspiron

I've been having several instances of Ubuntu randomly rebooting my laptop with not trace of an error message or clue to a reason why.

I've checked the system logs but frankly I'm too new to this to understand most of the messages. Can someone help me figure out where to start looking for a way to fix this problem.

Comment: What is output of `dmesg` command?

Comment: @P_Yadav here is a link to my dmesg right now => https://justpaste.it/37l96

The last random reboot was about 12 hours ago. I noticed thatthe dmesg contains a lot of messages that say "Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled."  Do you think that this has something to do with the random shutdowns?